# Making game with pure functional language

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to build a command-line game with F#, for my functional programming skill. With the game with simple structure, I could keep it's purity, like:

(Not strictly tested)

```
type HangmanGame = HangmanGame [char] string (deriving Show)

runGame :: Game -> IO Game
runGame (Game guessed answer) = do
    guess <- getLine
    -- validate guess
    -- do someting with guess
    runGame (Game guess:guessed answer)
```

I think the main concept of this simple hangman-like game is `Game guessed answer` is gone and replaced with `Game guess:guessed answer`. Since the game has only two fields, reconstructing it with new value is fairly easy. But when it comes to...

```
type ComplicatedGame = Game {
    a :: Int,
    b :: String,
    c :: Int,
    d :: String,
    ...
    z :: String
}
```

And when I want to change only `c`, I have to reconstruct the whole game value like `Game a b newC d ... z`.

Moreover, with the space-odyssey game system like

```
type Galaxy = Galaxy {
    name :: String,
    starSystems :: [StarSystem]
}

type StarSystem = StarSystem {
    name :: String,
    planets :: Planets
}

type Planet = Planet {
    name :: String,
    men :: [Human],
    buildings :: [Building]
}
```

And a single change of a number of `men` in a single planet would result the whole reconstruction of `Galaxy`!

Since I will make the UI system later with Unity3d and C#, I want to make my core code with F#. But I think banning mutability would result the situation above, which would not be the desired situation. But I also think just sticking to C# would be better rather than adopting mutability, which would not increase my functional programming skills.

Would you please give me suggestions for making and handling huge data structures (like above `Galaxy` example) via functional programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace only `c` in a `ComplicatedGame` value (let's call it `cg`), you can use a [copy-and-update expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/copy-and-update-record-expressions):

```
let c1 = { cg with c = newC }
```

You can nest these, if you'd like, although it does become awkward:

```
let g1 = { g with starSystems = { (* update one planet here...*) } }
```

(I haven't tried to compile, so I may have made some typos above.)

The awkwardness of having to write nested copy-and-update expressions has lead to [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) in Haskell, but since F# doesn't support type classes, there's no built-in equivalent in F#. You can hand-craft lenses in F#, but they're not nearly as nice as in Haskell.

When you use copy-and-update expressions, you're *not* rebuilding the entire universe. Values are immutable, so the data structures you don't touch are reused. It's quite efficient, but unlikely to be *as* efficient as mutation (although compiler optimisations might get you there).

Comment: In Haskell the equivalent is just `let g1 = g { starSystems = {- change here -}}`